# I'm trying to link pages but when i click on any of the sections on nav. bar for eg. Home new page opens showing this Your file couldn’t be accessed

Tags: html, css

```
<li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
<section class="home" id="home">
```

These are my code lines, IDE used is Brackets.

ON inspecting the page it is showing Not allowed to load local resource file:///E:/Web%20Designing/Resume/Assets/home

Comment: You need to use a webserver not a local copy of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a '#'

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>
```

Maybe adding a hash to navigate to a particular section of your page might help.

Id's can be referenced using #.